# When should I use blockingGet?

Tags: rx-java, reactivex

I am using RxJava a lot for work and seen some examples of calling a method which returns an Observable or Single and then calling blockingGet on it to use the results in a different . I was thinking this might be a misuse of the library and the concept but I might be wrong. I will give a small example:

```java
   public Observable<String> getStrings(){
     // return sg
   }

   public Observable<String> getNames(){
     // return names
   }

   public Observable<String> filterNamesInStrings() {
     List<String> names = getNames().toList().blockingGet();

     return getStrings().filter(str -> /*is str in names list*/)
   }
```

The `filterNamesInStrings` could also be solved by:

```java
   getNames()
    .toList()
    .flatMapObservable(names-> 
       getStrings().filter(str -> /*is str in names list*/)
```

My intuition is that the second solution is better, but the only reason I have is that I feel with using blockingGet we kind of break the chain of observables, lose the laziness (I'm not sure tho how lazy Rx is) but I did not find anything to prove my points also nothing to further explain that the second is better. Also if I am right I don't see any other use case for blocking get than quick testing, is that true?

My questions:

- Is my question a valid one or the difference is negligible between the implementations?
- Is any of the solutions better/more true to the library than the other, if so why and is there a valid reason to use blockingGet then?
- (Optional: Could you recommend me a good book on understanding the depths of ReactiveX, so I get explanations for questions like this and also a "good practices" list/book would be handy)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is my question a valid one or the difference is negligible between the implementations?

`blockingGet` blocks the current thread, so you almost certainly don't want to call it outside of tests. The second example is the right approach.

> Is any of the solutions better/more true to the library than the other, if so why and is there a valid reason to use blockingGet then?

Tests mainly. Or rarely, when working with fully synchronous code where blocking never actually happens.

> understanding the depths of ReactiveX

There is no book for this depth. All books about RxJava are fine to read.