# Return value in a method from an rx chain

Tags: java, rx-java

I have one function that passing one String returns another. But my problem is that using RxJava I don't know how to do to return the String value.

```java
        private void check(String value) {
            if (getGenderValue(value).equals("male")) {
               //do somehting
            }
        }

        private String getGenderValue(String value) {
              findGenderValueUseCase
                    .setType("somehting")
                    .setLanguage("language")
                    .setCountry("countryid")
                    .setValue(value)
                    .asObservable()
                    .compose(bindUntilEventDestroyView())
                    .subscribe(new NewSubscriber());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your method to:

```
        private void check(String value) {
              findGenderValueUseCase
                    .setType("somehting")
                    .setLanguage("language")
                    .setCountry("countryid")
                    .setValue(value)
                    .asObservable()
                    .compose(bindUntilEventDestroyView())
                    .subscribe(value ->
                        if (getGenderValue(value).equals("male")) {
                         //do somehting
                        }
                    );
        }
```

But bear in mind as it's an observable, "do something" will be executed for each value emitted.

Or if you want to achieve it in a blocking way:

```
        private void check(String value) {
          if (getGenderValue(value).equals("male")) {
           //do somehting
          }
        }

        private String getGenderValue(String value) {
              return findGenderValueUseCase
                    .setType("somehting")
                    .setLanguage("language")
                    .setCountry("countryid")
                    .setValue(value)
                    .asObservable()
                    .compose(bindUntilEventDestroyView())
                    .blockingFirst(); // here we only return the first value
        }
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56629061/1401164) in order to understand which one is best.